# Dynamic adding elements to Zend Subform via AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework, zend-form

I have a registration multipage form that i have built using Zend_Form and Zend_SubForm.

The problem is that on some subforms I need to load other elements based on the user choice:

If user chooses one category the filters appended to that category have to be loaded. If he chooses another category than another filter set need to be loaded. How can I build such thing?

Comment: To use send form validation you would probably need to create all possible elements in zend_form and then jQuery to show/hide/filter elements based on user input.

Comment: @Gavin Thank you, but I don't think this is a good solution. I have over 200 categories, each with subcategories and sub-subcategories. I only imagine what the loading time will be.

Comment: Need to see db schema and some code